# Why Does Gradle Do An Up To Date Check When No History Is Available?

Tags: gradle

I have a task that copies some large files (250MB each). The task looks a bit like this (but with more files)

```
task copyWars {
    outputs.files (
            "deploy/war1.war",
            "deploy/war2.war"
    )
    doLast {
        copy {
            from "deploy"
            into "deploy"
            include 'root.war'
            rename 'root.war', 'war1.war'
        }
        copy {
            from "deploy"
            into "deploy"
            include 'root.war'
            rename 'root.war', 'war2.war'
        }
    }
}
```

When I run I get a message like this:

```
Executing task ':copyWars' (up-to-date check took 5 mins 2.918 secs) due to:
  No history is available.
```

Gradle seems to want to do an up-to-date check even when there is no history available.
Since these are large files it takes a while to do the check.

Why would it do a check when there is no history?

Comment: Not sure. Do you get the same with a task of type `Copy` (which should be used here in any case)?

Comment: How do I use the Copy task here if I am copying and renaming the same file 9 times?